# Problem solving a differential equation $y'=y+y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving this differential equation:

$$y'=y+y^2$$
I tried the substitution $$z=y^{-1}\\z'=-y^{-2}y'$$ and the differential equation becomes $z'+z=-1$ and now I have as solution $$z=ce^{-x}-1$$ and $$y=\frac{1}{ce^{-x}-1}$$ 
But the solution is not correct. Does  someone can find my error?

Comment: "But the solution is not correct" Your book probably gives an equivalent formulation of your solution, for example, $$y=\frac{ce^x}{1-ce^x}$$

Comment: @SpamIAm No. $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply differentiate $y$:

$$y'=-1(ce^{-x}-1)^{-2}(-ce^{-x})=\frac{ce^{-x}}{(ce^{-x}-1)^2}=y+y^2$$

You're right, as Did mentioned in the comments the book probably wrote:

$$y=\frac{ce^x}{1-ce^x}$$

Another way of solving this is:

$$\frac{dy}{y+y^2}=dx$$

$$\ln\left|\frac{y}{y-1}\right|=x+C$$

Solving for $y$ gives the same expression.

Comment: Oh. thank you. I did not notice it. That's really embarrassing.